# Group list active item appears 2 times in a list

Tags: python, django

Im writing program that shows static schedule for school organisations and now there is a page of schedule with relevant days-lessons, but the title of the day appears 2 times. Here is a screenshot of my issue:

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esx75.png)

Here is the html code of the page

`schedule.html`

```
{% extends 'app/layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
<ul class="list-group">
{% for i in subjects %}
<li class="list-group-item active" aria-current="true">{{i.day}}</li>
<li class="list-group-item " aria-current="true">{{i.title}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock body %}
```

`views.py`

```
def showSchedule(request, ID):
    relevant_group = Students.objects.get(id = ID)
    subjects = relevant_group.students.all().order_by("day")
    context = {"group": relevant_group, "subjects":subjects}
    return render(request, "app/schedule.html", context)
```

my `models`:

```
class Students(models.Model):
group_year = models.IntegerField()
group_title = models.ForeignKey(Faculty, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
group_number = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.group_year}{self.group_title}-{self.group_number}"

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('group_year', 'group_title', 'group_number')
```

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = "subject")
    timeslot = models.IntegerField()
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = "teacher")
    cabinet = models.IntegerField()
    day = models.ForeignKey(DaysOfWeek, on_delete= models.CASCADE ,related_name = "day")
    group = models.ForeignKey(Students, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name= "students")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} is teached by {self.teacher}"

    class Meta:
         unique_together = ('teacher', 'timeslot', 'cabinet')
```

```
class DaysOfWeek(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="name", max_length=10, unique=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id} - {self.name}"
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
```

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

How to make this blue(active item) Friday appear just 1 time?

Comment: Could you please also add your associated model class for a better understanding of the data structure,

Comment: debug or print out the `subjects` context and see if it's returning multiple of the same value

Comment: @dostogircse171 I added models

Comment: @LinhNguyen it is not returning multiple times the same value i just added the lessons with the same title(Subject) but they are on a different timeslot (1,2)

Comment: Please add Subject and DaysOfWeek model class as well.

Comment: @KhqyOp - Can't see it yet. Could you please recheck?

Comment: @dostogircse171 sorry, i wrote it wrong in the template, i fixed it

Comment: @KhqyOp I provide a simple solution in the answer I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is to update your `schedule.html` template and check if in the loop the previous day is the same as the current day. You can do it by using Django `with` variable declaration and filters like below:

```
{% extends 'app/layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
<ul class="list-group">
{% for i in subjects %}
    {% with forloop.counter0|subtract:1 as prev_index %}
        {% if forloop.first or i.day != subjects|slice:prev_index %}
            <li class="list-group-item active" aria-current="true">{{i.day}}</li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    <li class="list-group-item " aria-current="true">{{i.title}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock body %}
```

Please note `forloop.counter0` starting at 0.

Feel free to ask questions in the comments if you need any clarifications.